# JavaScript field logged to console is always "undefined"

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

It's the first time i use objects with JavaScript, i used the method 1.1 from [this tutorial](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class), i have this code:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.currentTime = 0;

    this.start = function() {
        this.currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(this.currentTime); //this line prints the time i just set
        this.intervalID = setInterval(this.step, 25);
    };
    this.step = function() {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(this.currentTime); //always prints "undefined" to the console
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
    };
}
```

The problem is that in the `step()` function, `console.log(this.currentTime)`always prints "undefined", while `this.currentTime` was set in the `start()` function.

Why? What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the scope of the function `this.fn` in each case, that's why you're not adding it to the `MyClass`'s scope. You have to store the `this` object and use it to add properties.

```
function MyClass() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    var self = this;
    this.start = function() {
        self.currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(self.currentTime); //this line prints the time i just set
        self.intervalID = setInterval(self.step, 25);
    };
    this.step = function() {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(self.currentTime); //always prints "undefined" to the console
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(self.intervalID);
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! if it's better to use `prototype`, i'll switch to it. Ok now that it works, why if i call another function inside a function, either using `this` or `self` the result is `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'myFunction'`? the function is defined as the `step` function, but i'm calling it in the `stop` function as `self.myFunction()`

Comment: Where is that function defined? Update your answer please!

Comment: It was my mistake, i used `this.self = this` instead of `var self=this`, now everything works, thanks!